# Extracting substring with specific starting/ending strings in Informix

Tags: sql, substring, informix

Suppose a string like this `... banana ... tomato ...`. How to extract the substring that begins with `banana` and ends with `tomato` so that the result is `banana ... tomato`.

I'm using IBM Informix Dynamic Server Version 11.50.FC8W4.

Comment: can you use regex?

Comment: Does INFORMIX support regex? @vkp

Comment: Thank you for including the version information — that's a help.

Comment: I'm tolerably sure there isn't a standard built-in function in Informix that will do the job trivially — in 11.50 or 11.70 or 12.10. There is (was?) a 'regex' datablade that could be added to Informix that would probably make the job easier. It would be possible, but fairly fiddly, to write appropriate SPL (stored procedure language) code that would do the job. Is that string small enough to fit into a VARCHAR(255), or do you have to worry about using LVARCHAR? Fundamentally, you'll need to find the offset of the `b` of `banana`, and the offset of the final `o` of `tomato` and then use SUBSTR.

Answer (score 0):

may be matches could help you.
select * from customer
where company matches 'banana*tomato'